# sql converting value error

Tags: sql, sql-server, nvarchar

I am getting this error for `ItemCode` column:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '8KAM69631KX' to data type int

I'm using the following code:

```sql
CREATE table #SatisStokSDH (
    STORECODE nvarchar(50), 
    STORESTOCK int, 
    ItemCode nvarchar(50), 
    ColorCode nvarchar(50), 
    Sales_Unit_L7 int, 
    SDH int
)

insert into #SatisStokSDH (STORECODE, STORESTOCK, ItemCode, ColorCode, Sales_Unit_L7, SDH)
select STORECODE,
       STORESTOCK,
       ItemCode,
       ColorCode,
       Sales_Unit_L7,
       STORESTOCK/NULLIF(Sales_Unit_L7,0)*7 as SDH
       from #SatisStok
```

Why am i getting this error? And how can that be corrected?

Comment: Because  string 8KAM69631KX does not represent a valid int

Comment: What column is that in?  That is not an int,  are you trying to insert the value into an int table or it is in your column with the calculation.

Provide sample data from the table and that will show you what column it is

Comment: What is in the table you are selecting from?

Comment: `8KAM69631KX` which belongs to ? what column in you table

Comment: What's the definition (and content) of your temp table "#SatisStok" ?

Comment: That is only the first of your problems. Looks at your calculation. If Sales_Unit_L7 is null you have told it to divide by 0. Maybe that should be a 1?

Comment: See this for a great place to get some ideas about how you can improve this question so that you get an answer. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Actually Sean, you have that slightly wrong, and have confused NULLIF with ISNULL. If *Sales_Unit_L7* is zero it will divide STORESTOCK by a null - and get null.

Comment: I just deleted my temp table and created again. And it did work! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to insert nvarchar field to int field. please change the datatype of the relevant column belong to '8KAM69631KX'